# Search on custom field other than the Record Name field

Tags: search

When I create a custom object called Gym, a default text field called Gym Name is created for me. This field is used to search (using the Search bar on the left) for records of the Gym objects.

How do I go about getting Salesforce to search on a custom field other than Gym Name ?

Comment: All searchable fields are searched so long as the Allow Search on the object is checked https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_search_allow_custom_objects.htm

Answer (score 2):

All searchable fields are searched so long as the Allow Search on the object is checked

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_search_allow_custom_objects.htm

> Previously, all your org’s custom objects were searchable by default
>   via the API, and the Salesforce user interface when associated with a
>   custom tab. The search index stored each custom object’s record
>   information, even if you didn’t need the information to be searchable.
>   Making a custom object searchable when you don’t need your users to
>   find its records slows down searches across your org.
>
> If you don’t need a custom object’s records to be searchable, disable
>   search for that custom object. Disabling search for custom objects
>   doesn’t change the way your org interacts with the objects outside of
>   search.
>
> In Winter ’16, search is disabled by default for new custom objects.